# Java: String index out of range: -1

Tags: java, string, range, out

New code:

I have no idea what's going on here, I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1949)
    at client0_0_2.loginToClient(client0_0_2.java:98)
    at client0_0_2.general(client0_0_2.java:196)
    at client0_0_2.<init>(client0_0_2.java:208)
    at client0_0_2.main(client0_0_2.java:215)
```

and this is the contents of the method that's causing the error:

```
public String loginToClient() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    //decryptUsers();
    int tries;
    tries = 5;
    while (tries > 0) {
        System.out.println("LOGIN");
        String usnm = c.readLine("Username: ");
        char [] passwd = c.readPassword("Password: ");
        users = new FileInputStream("users.fra");
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(users);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));
        String logindat = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(logindat);
        int startUsnm = logindat.indexOf(usnm);
        String logdat = logindat.substring(startUsnm, logindat.indexOf("."));
        if (startUsnm == -1) {
            System.err.println("Username not recognised, please try another or create user.");
            usnm = "INV";
            return usnm;
        }
        else {
            int tendUsnm = logdat.indexOf(':'); 
            int startPass = endUsnm + 1;
            int tendPass = logdat.indexOf('.');
            String Usnm = logdat.substring("0", tendUsnm);
            String Pass = logdat.substring(startPass, endPass);
            char [] Passwd = Pass.toCharArray();
            if (usnm.equals(Usnm)) {
                if (Arrays.equals(passwd,Passwd)) {
                    System.out.println ("Logged in. Welcome, " + usnm + ".");
                    String data = "LOGIN: " + usnm;
                    printLog(data);
                    //encryptUsers();
                    return usnm;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println ("Incorrect password, please try again.");
                    String data = "PASWFAIL: " + usnm;
                    printLog(data);
                    tries -= 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println ("Username not recognised.");
                printLog("USNAMFAIL");
                usnm = "INV";
                return usnm;
                //encrytUsers();
            }
        }
    }
    //encryptUsers();
    System.exit(2);
    return usnm;
}
```

It looks kinda like it's trying to access the last character of something and that's upsetting it, but I have no idea why. Any help for a total newbie?

edits:

`users.fra` contains `username:password` at the time of execution.

note: line 98 is the

```
char [] Passwd = Pass.toCharArray();
```

n.b. not homework, a personal project.

Will add in a method to deal with the event that username is not in `users.fra`.

Comment: Please provide an example that causes this behavior

Comment: I don't think this is line 98 `char [] Passwd = Pass.toCharArray();`

Comment: i believe the compiler may have pinpointed the wrong line, as it sometimes does.

Answer (score 3):

`indexOf()` returns -1 when the argument can't be found. I bet that the string you are searching does not have one of the characters you are searching for and it is causing an invalid index when you try to get a substring.

Comment: Thanks! It shouldn't be... it's finding a plaintext username and password in a file containing only "username:password.", so I presume I've screwed up one of the searches...

Answer (score 3):

try to use `contains()` before `indexOf()` for yor string to avoid the situations when `indexOf()` returns -1 and you try to get substring with the -1 position.

Comment: How exactly should I use `contains()`?

Comment: e.g.: `if(myString.contains(someChar) && myString.contains(someOhterChar)) {
String subString = myString.substring(myString.indexOf(someChar), myString.indexOf(someOhterChar))`

Answer (score 2):

`String().indexOf` will return -1 if there is no match

`String().substring` will throw an `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` if you give it a negative `begin` value.

This is all documented at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Thus, I'd look at this line of code:

```
String logdat = logindat.substring(startUsnm, logindat.indexOf("."));
```

This will fail if `usnm` is not in `logindat`

Comment: substring() Throws:
IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things can be wrong. You'll have to check what is printed.

An exemple :

```
int startUsnm = logindat.indexOf(usnm);
String logdat = logindat.substring(startUsnm, logindat.indexOf("."));
```

If you don't have "Username: " in logindat, it produces the exception you see.

EDIT : Note that if you want to allow "username:" (and not only "Username:"), you can do this :

```
 int startUsnm = logindat.toLowerCase().indexOf("username:");
```

And test that startUsnm is >= 0.

Answer (score 0):

You should really look at those lines:

```
        int startUsnm = logindat.indexOf(usnm);
        int tendUsnm = logdat.indexOf(':');
        int endUsnm = startUsnm + tendUsnm;
        int startPass = endUsnm + 1;
        int tendPass = logdat.indexOf('.');
        int endPass = startPass + tendPass;
        String Usnm = logindat.substring(startUsnm, endUsnm);
        String Pass = logindat.substring(startPass, endPass);
```

Suppose you have file like this:

---

user:pass.

---

so:

- startUsnm = 0 //first char
- tendUsnm = 4 // index of `:` char
- endUsnm = 4 // sum? this is probably not what you intent to do
- startPass = 5 // `p` char
- tendPass = 9 // `.` char
- endPass = 14 // sum again? Those integers are indexes - will throw IndexOutOfBounds

And consider also that `indexOf` will return `-1` value if there is no such match in given `String`.

Comment: the summed integers are for if the username required is not the first in the users.fra file; id est, it may contain "username:password.usrn:pass." and I only seek usrn, not username. This should give me the position of the end of the username  with respect to the whole string. Which I've just realised is a pointless exercise, as I have a string which is only the index of usrn through to "."... Will now adjust.